# Accessing data from form array with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form like this

```
<form>
 <input type="text" name="personal_details[]" />
 <input type="text" name="personal_details[]" />

 <input type="text" name="pictures[]" />
 <input type="text" name="pictures[]" />
</form>
```

With php I can access data like this

```
$name    = $_POST['personal_details'][0];
$surname = $_POST['personal_details'][1];
etc.. etc
```

Is it possible to do this task with codeigniter input class ?

Answer (score 2):

They work basically the same.

```
$personal_details = $this->input->post('personal_details');
$pictures = $this->input->post('pictures');

$name = $personal_details[0];
$surname = $personal_details[1];
```

Comment: I just wondering if there is another way.
Something like $this->input->post('var', [0, 1 , 2 etc]);
Regarding user guide there is no such way to get data

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html. CI has some of *the* best docs you will find

Answer (score 0):

A form like the following, taken from the example above plus some additions.

```
<form>
 <input type="text" name="personal_details[]" />
 <input type="text" name="personal_details[]" />

 <input type="text" name="pictures[]" />
 <input type="text" name="pictures[]" />

 <input type="text" name="details[first_name]" />
 <input type="text" name="details[last_name]" />
</form>
```

This can be used within your controller or model like the following.

```
echo $this->input->post( 'personal_details' )[ 0 ];
echo $this->input->post( 'personal_details' )[ 1 ];
echo $this->input->post( 'pictures' )[ 0 ];
echo $this->input->post( 'pictures' )[ 1 ];

echo $this->input->post( 'details' )[ 'first_name' ];
echo $this->input->post( 'details' )[ 'last_name' ];
```

I hope that this helps.  I was wondering the same thing and experimented until I found this solution.